# How to copy a large number of small files into OneDrive & have it successfully sync

Tags: windows, onedrive, file-copying

I have ~600,000 small files (~9kb each) that I want to move into my OneDrive. The why is because OneDrive is the system my company uses.

My challenge is that OneDrive seems to freeze and not sync if I copy all 600k files at once. This is documented elsewhere (just one example):
https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/common-onedrive-problems-and-how-to-fix-them
the proposed solution is to copy "slower". I've read that copying >1000 files tends to freeze OneDrive

My current best solution is this command which will take +85 hrs to complete:

```
    robocopy /ipg:510 /E "source" "destination"
```

I've found that if I set the ipg too low (e.g. <450), one drive will sometimes sync and other times not. I think it has a feature that checks to see if the user is still making changes to a file/folder and only updates once changes aren't happening anymore. If the ipg is set too low, I suspect that OneDrive thinks I'm still doing something and waits to sync, eventually leading to the freeze. At 510, my experience is that OneDrive can catch up and sync every file.

I want to know if there is a more efficient solution. While my solution works, its 85 hrs of up time that may need to be spread over 3 weeks. I've read that this issue with OneDrive occurs if the user is copying >1000 files at a time. An idea that I've had, but can't implement is copy groups of files all at once. e.g. copy X files over to OneDrive, wait until they sync, then repeat.

Some restrictions:

- no admin access
- cannot install new programs (windows 10)
- preserves folder structure
  If solution takes > 10 hrs
- Allow for interruption and restarts

Comment: Can you locally add them to a `.zip` then upload the `.zip`?